# Load and use alpha channel bitmap

Tags: opengl

Considering the following alpha channel bitmap:

```
const int width = 4, height = 4;
var alpha = new byte[width * height] {
    255, 255, 255, 255,
      0, 127, 127,   0,
      0, 127, 127,   0,
    255, 255, 255, 255
};
```

I would like to load it into OpenGl and use it into fragment shader as:

```
out vec4 color;
void main() {
    float alpha = // Get pixel alpha like texture()
    color = vec4(1, 0, 0, alpha);
}
```

I know it is possible to use a RGBA Bitmap texture but is it possible to use only Alpha channel bitmap texture ? (from the simplest `byte[]` type)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to use an alpha channel bitmap, you can use a 1 channel bitmap texture as in:

`glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RED, width, height, 0, GL_RED, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, byteBuffer);`

Here with `GL_RED` we are saying that we want only want a texture with one channel (red)
So in the fragment shader you can do
`float alpha = texture(...).r;`

Comment: Thank you very much! I am trying it

Comment: No worries! Let me know if you need further explanation.

Comment: @Rabbid76 Yes i stand corrected, i made the necessary changes to the answer. Thanks!